# On what ubuntu/linux version is elementary based on

Tags: drivers

Let me start by saying that I'm an absolute noob here. Barely 24 hours on a linux based system. So please don't mind if my framing of the question seems uninformed or noobish.
Here is the main issue- 
I want to install drivers for my laptop and none of the divers say 'for elementary os' they say 'ubuntu';'bsd';'linux' and so on.
So, I wanted to know which one of these is elementary based on so that I can download and install it for my elementary -
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaWnG.jpg

This answer will help me install other such softwares too. Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check
[this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_OS#Summary_table) link for the version you installed. You probably have installed Loki which is based on Ubuntu 16.04
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can also see this by going to System settings > About. In the case of Loki it will mention something like:

> Build on "Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS"

P.S: You can download the drivers that are meant for Ubuntu. That should work.